# Saving a String of Integers

Tags: java, string, integer, save, isbn

I am working on a problem related to **ISBN book codes**. I need to make the program so that input is given with 9 digits of the needed 10 digit code. **The 10th one is a '?'**. The program needs to output the appropriate number. I started by splitting the input String into two sub-Strings wherever '?' is detected.

My question is **HOW TO GET EACH INTEGER FROM THE INPUT STRING** (SO I CAN MULTIPLY THOSE INTEGERS WITH CERTAIN NUMBERS TO GET THE FINAL ANSWER)

for example : Input String is: '**01234?6789**'

**How do I extract all the digits from this string, so that all mathematical operations are possible to be performed on these digits**

Comment: You forgot to ask your problem :)

Comment: You mean `int a = Integer.parseInt(split[0]), b = Integer.parseInt(split[1])`?

Comment: Where is your question and what you have tried?

Comment: Looks like homework. Just split the string and try all 10 digits in place of '?'. If the check digit algorithm says it's OK: bingo!

Comment: @SURESHATTA I did ask a question. Anyways I rephrased it so its more clear.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanweera - I tried splitting the string with delimiter '?', the code snippet for which is :   
       String[] parts = isbn.split("\\?");
       String part1 = parts[0]; 
       String part2 = parts[1];

Comment: @laune : thanks for the problem solving, but I still need an answer to how to save individual digits from the input string, so that mathematical operations can be performed on the same.

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson I used this code to split the input String into two parts (one part for before the '?' and one part after it).
The code snippet is:
 String[] parts = isbn.split("\\?"); //isbn-name of input string
       String part1 = parts[0]; 
       String part2 = parts[1];

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help you?

```
private static int getCharAsInt(int x, String number) {
        if ((int) number.charAt(x) - 48 > 9){
            //do something if the char is "?"
            //maybe return -1 to know its not a number you can use
            return -1;
        }
        else //return the char as an int
            return (int) number.charAt(x) - 48;
    }
```

This method will return the `char` of the `String` "number" at position x as an `int` and will return `-1` when it finds the `"?"`. Not that you can make it do anything else you like when you find the `"?"`.

Anyway when you call it like that :

```
String string = "01234?6789";
for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++)
    System.out.print(getCharAsInt(i, string) + " ");
```

The output will be:

```
0 1 2 3 4 -1 6 7 8 9
```

Of course the method returns an `int` so you can call it and perform any operations you want to get the final answer.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the help. But how can I call these individual integers and perform mathematical operations on them. I mean what is the name I would use of the individual variable to call them.
for example, I intend to use 2 from that string. How am I supposed to call it from the above example. And it would be great if you answered using the same example you used as above.

Comment: ok so you can do the following:
`int x = getCharAsInt(1, "01234?6789")` this will store the 2nd char (char at index 1) as integer. So after that, `x = 1` for this particualr example.

Comment: You can create an `array` of `int`s. Create a `for` loop and on each iteration call this method. After you have filled the array you can call `array[i]` and get that value and perform any kind of operation. I am not sure what kinds of operations you want so the optimal way to do it may vary. But in general you can get a value out of a `string` with this method and store it somewhere and then manipulate it as you wish

Comment: And a lame question now please, How do I call this function getCharAsint into the main function, so that the function 'getCharAsint' executes perfectly.

Comment: Instead of having 10 variables you can have an `int[]` Array of size `10` then in a for loop you store each value there. Then if you want the first digit you call `array[0]` if you want the second you call `array[1]`, the third, `array[2]` and so on. You can also change the value of an array index so for example if the `?` is at index 4 you can perform some calculation and store a value back on index 4. for example `array[4] = calculateMissingInt();` etc. When you can the result you can get each value of the Array and for the final answer.

Comment: Also about your second question. This method returns something. So you have perform an operation on it. Like print whatever it returns or add it somewhere or whatever. Hope that makes sense to you. Its pretty basic stuff

Answer (score 0):

This contains a few statement sequences you should study. See the comments.

```
// checks whether the ten digits in the int[] make up a valid ISBN-10
private boolean isValid( int[] digits ){
    int sum = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++ ){
        sum += (10 - i)*digits[i];
    }
    return sum % 11 == 0;
}

// Expect a string with 9 or 19 digits and at most one '?'
public String examine( String isbn ){
    if( isbn.length() != 10 )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "string length " + isbn.length() );
    if( ! isbn.matches( "\\d*\\??\\d*" ) )
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "string contains invalid characters" );
    // Now we have 9 or 10 digits and at most one question mark.
    // Convert char values to int values by subtracting the integer value of '0'
    int qmPos = -1;
    int[] digit = new int[10];
    for( int iDig = 0;  iDig < isbn.length(); iDig++ ){
        char c = isbn.charAt(iDig);
        if( c == '?' ){
             qmPos = iDig;
             digit[iDig] = 0;
        } else {
            digit[iDig] = c - (int)'0';
        }
    }
    // If qmPos is still -1, there's no '?'
    if( qmPos == -1 ){
        // Is it a valid ISBN-10?
        if( isValid( digit ) ){
            return Arrays.toString( digit );
        } else {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException( "not a valid ISBN" );
        }
    }

    // Which digit can replace '?'?
    for( int probe = 0; probe <= 9; probe++ ){
        digit[qmPos] = probe;
        if( isValid( digit ) ){
            // found it - return the completed ISBN-10
            return Arrays.toString( digit );
        }
    }
    // Failure
    throw new IllegalArgumentException( "no digit completes an ISBN" );
}
```